# MATLAB vs. Python Binary File Read

Tags: python, matlab, binaryfiles, readfile

I have a MATLAB application that reads a .bin file and parses through the data. I am trying to convert this script from MATLAB to Python but am seeing discrepancies in the values being read.

The read function utilized in the MATLAB script is:

```matlab
fname = 'file.bin';
f=fopen(fname);
data = fread(f, 100);
fclose(f);
```

The Python conversion I attempted is: (**edited**)

```py
fname = 'file.bin'
with open(fname, mode='rb') as f:
    data= list(f.read(100))
```

I would then print a side-by-side comparison of the read bytes with their index and found discrepancies between the two. I have confirmed that the values read in Python are correct by executing `$ hexdump -n 100 -C file.bin` and by viewing the file's contents on the application HexEdit.

I would appreciate any insight into the source of discrepancies between the two programs and how I may be able to resolve it.

Note: I am trying to only utilize built-in Python libraries to resolve this issue.

**Solution**: Utilizing incorrect file path/structure between programming languages. Implementing @juanpa.arrivillaga's suggestion cleanly reproduced the MATLAB results.

Comment: Um, this is completely redundant: `int(hex(ord(i)),16)` can just be `ord(i)`, IOW, `int(hex(whatever), 16) == whatever`

Comment: Also, `data = [int(hex(ord(i)),16) for i in bytes]` would raise a `TypeError`, because `i` is an `int`, and `ord(i)` is expecting a `str` of length 1. You really must provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

An exact translation of the MATLAB code, using NumPy, would be:

```py
data = np.frombuffer(f.read(100), dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this reproduced the same results as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested, except as a float64.

Comment: @Alex This is exactly MATLAB’s behavior. Are you sure you get a different result in MATLAB? Are you sure you’re referencing the same file? If things really don’t match up with the same file, please include the file in your post (or at least the hex dump of the first 100 values), and show us what MATLAB’s output is and what Python’s output is.

Answer (score 0):

python automatically transforms single bytes into unsigned integers, as done by matlab, so you just need to do the following.

```py
fname = 'file.bin'
with open(fname, mode='rb') as f:
    bytes_arr = f.read(100)
    # Conversion for visual comparison purposes
    data = [x for x in bytes_arr]
print(data)
```

also welcome to python, [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) is a built-in type, so please don't override the built-in `bytes` type ... or you'll run into unexpected problems.

Edit: as pointed by @juanpa.arrivillaga you could use the faster

```py
fname = 'file.bin'
with open(fname, mode='rb') as f:
    bytes_arr = f.read(100)
    # Conversion for visual comparison purposes
    data = list(bytes_arr)
```

Comment: `data = [x for x in bytes_arr]` -> `list(bytes_arr)`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. This does improve the clarity of the code but, does not resolve the underlying issue of the read discrepancies.

Comment: @Alex it does solve the underlying issue of discrepancies, if you are getting different results then the problem is not in this block of code.